# Set value of input in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Site:

> http://tinyurl.com/ah9hkgz

Issue: I'm trying to write simple javascript function to calculate subtotals and totals of order for customer. I got arrows to increment/decrement values for each product.

Tried to write function cash(qty); that is called onclick together with other "inline javascript" codes. On site, only first product's UP arrow is calling cash function.

When function cash is called, the `document.getelementbyid('szett_subtotal').Value=price;` doesn't work.

cash function:

```
function cash(qty)
{
   var price = 0;
   price = 12990 + ((qty.value-1)*9990); 
   document.getelementbyid('szett_subtotal').Value=price;
)
```

Thanks for your help. I hope.

**Clarification**

Down button does not contain this cash function call because I am focusing on up button for test purpose.

Comment: I fixed the case-sensitivity as Lion suggested. The down button is not issue. I was testing it on up button first. When that is sorted, I believe the down button will be easy stuff to complete ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function declaration of `cash` causes a parse error:

```
function cash(qty)
{
   var price = 0;
   price = 12990 + ((qty.value-1)*9990); 
   document.getElementById('szett_subtotal').value=price; 
)
^
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Function body should end with a curly end brace `}`.

Also, don't use inline JavaScript code, it's error prone and adding behaviour from outside the HTML is preferred, such as `.addEventListener()`.

The easiest to do is create a click handler function and call *that* from inline:

```
function inc_quantity(v)
{
  var qty_el = document.getElementById(v);
  var qty = qty_el.value;
  if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;
  cash(qty_el);
}

  ... onclick="inc_quantity('quantity_szett')"
```

Comment: I opened Firebug and wondered what cash not defined means.. you saved hours of my time waste !!! THANKS

Comment: @Skuta Take note of the second part of my answer as well; it should help reduce those big swathes of inline code you have now :)

Comment: Yep, I'll think about it - if it's needed as there are only few sites like this i have :D

Answer (score 0):

`Value` should be `value`, and `getelementbyid` should be `getElementById`.

```
document.getElementById('szett_subtotal').value=price;
```

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Concentrate on the function identifier - `getElementById()`

Comment: According to the asker, it works for the up button but not the down button. We need to find a difference in the code for the up and down buttons. For example, note the absence of a method call on the down button's `onclick` in the linked source code. Good point, though, about the method calls--I did not notice that.

Comment: Math, sorry, it is not working for up button  (and I do not care for down button yet as up doesn't work yet).

Comment: @Skuta Change getelementbyid to getElementById. Captalize the E, B, and I.

Comment: Yes, I changed the case-sensitivity on the website and copy pasted your code to be megasure. Doesn't work. :(

Comment: Refresh the page with the `F5` key (not `F` and `5`, `F5`). It works for me--the values change.

Comment: Just for kicks, in your `cash` function, use `document.getElementById('szett_subtotal').innerHTML=price;`, with `innerHTML` instead of `value`. Do it **only here** -- not on any other elements or code.

Answer (score 0):

On the down button, your page has:

```
var qty_el = document.getElementById('quantity_szett'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) && qty > 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;
```

On the up button, however, it says:

```
var qty_el = document.getElementById('quantity_szett'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;cash(document.getElementById('quantity_szett'));return false;
```

Call the `cash` function on the down button's `onclick`. Computers have **no common sense** and will not call `cash` for the down button even if the up button does.

I.E. add

```
cash(document.getElementById('quantity_szett'));
```

right before the `return false` of your down button's `onclick`.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Does this reply mean you can see the value change if you press up button? Cause I can't.

Comment: I can't replace it with qty.value because qty.value is number of products and "szett_subtotal" is where I want the price to go.

Comment: I did not test the page--I just looked at the source and saw that you didn't call `cash`. Follow Lion's suggestion too--change `Value` to `value` *and* `getelementbyid` to `getElementById`. Also, did you intend to not call `cash`? The question implied that the only problem was that the down button didn't call `cash`, and that that was unwanted--sorry if I misinterpreted.

Comment: I understand your confusion with my post, the thing is -> I need to fix why UP button doesn't work. Don't worry to click on the page, there is no virus there and it is the first product, first up arrow :)

Comment: I did those changes right now on website (case sensitivity) and nothing changed.

Comment: That would be under Lion's answer.